# How to prevent HP-UX command "less" from messing up my prompt?

Tags: less, hp-ux, more

I don't like the output of `more` on HP-UX, so I use `less` instead as a
pager:

```
PAGER=less
```

Its output is nice, but, on Linux, when I use `man` and then quit, I
go back to the shell, and the display looks just the way I left it,
but on HP-UX, when I go back to the shell, there is a partial line left before the prompt, much like the following command produces:

```
echo -e "text \c"
```

Look at this:

- on HP-UX:

  ```
  user@hpux2:~$ man ls
  Riformattazione in corso. Attendere...user@hpux2:~$
  ```

(the message in Italian means "Reformatting in progress, please wait")

- on Linux:

  ```
  user@linux:~$ man ls
  user@linux:~$
  ```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you quit by giving `q` or using `CTRL+C`. I have a HPUX machine and it seems to return to the new line ( similar to linux ) if i give `q` or `CTRL+C`. I have `EDITOR=vi` in my environment variables.

Comment: Of course q,i have EDITOR=vim,i try also EDITOR=vi but nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen swapping is done with a terminal control code.  Such codes are documented under `terminfo(5)`.  The two involved in the screen saving/restoring are typically `smcup` and `rmcup`.  The first turns on a special cursor addressing mode of the terminal (sm="set mode") and the second one turns it off.  Typically, these two will save the screen and restore it.

If screen restoring isn't working, it's possible that those entries are incorrect for your terminal type.  You can print the contents of the current terminfo entry using the `infocmp` command.  You'll need to look at those entries (`smcup` and `rmcup`) and compare the escape sequences with your terminal manual to determine what they do.  Odds are your terminal is just *slightly* different from the one expected by the terminfo entry.

Comment: Probably there is some bug with hpux xterm,using dtterm as terminal work fine
also for man

Comment: That's a possibility.  Sometimes a terminal emulator will claim to be "such-and-such compatible" but leave things out.  When the system then defines the terminal type as "such-and-such", the display gets messed up.  It could also be that HP's xterm has a special value to be used for TERM and it's not being set properly (maybe a profile changing it?).

Answer (score 2):

The feature mentioned is xterm's *alternate screen* which was introduced in X.V10R4 (December 1986).  Although the feature was supported, it was not added to the terminal description until X11R6 (about ten years).

HPUX's terminal description for `xterm` happens to be the same as the X11R5 description, with some additions (mainly function keys 1-12).  Again, the feature (function keys) had been supported by the program for some time, but was not added to the terminal description.

Here's what `infocmp` reports for HPUX:

```
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/lib/terminfo/x/xterm
xterm|vs100|xterm terminal emulator,
        am, km, xenl,
        cols#80, lines#65,
        bel=^G, blink=@, bold=\E[1m, civis=\E[?25I,
        clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?25h, cr=\r,
        csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\b,
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\E[B, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
        cvvis=\E[?25h, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
        dl1=\E[M, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, home=\E[1;1H, ht=\t,
        hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@, ich1=\E[@, il=\E[%p1%dL,
        il1=\E[L, ind=\n, kbs=\177, kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB,
        kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
        kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf2=\EOQ, kf3=\EOR,
        kf4=\EOS, kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~,
        kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~, rc=\E8,
        rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rmkx=\E[?1l, rmso=\E[m,
        rs1=\E>\E[1;3;4;5;6l\E[?7h\E[m\E[r\E[2J\E[H, rs2=@,
        sc=\E7,
        sgr=\E[%?%p1%t;7%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p6%t;1%;m,
        sgr0=\E[m, smkx=\E[?1h, smso=\E[7m, tbc=\E[3g,
```

Here are links to the [X11R6 file](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/blob/279c9960fc4d19e249ec7af2fb7c7d9c2987d369/terminfo), and the [X11R3](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/blob/279c9960fc4d19e249ec7af2fb7c7d9c2987d369/terminfo) (unchanged through X11R5).  The alternate screen feature in the X11R6 terminal description is [provided by this line](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/blob/279c9960fc4d19e249ec7af2fb7c7d9c2987d369/terminfo#L30):

```
smcup=\E7\E[?47h, rmcup=\E[2J\E[?47l\E8,
```

With ncurses (Linux, etc), you have a [much later terminal description](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo.html) which lists all of the applicable features.

For HPUX, you could fix the problem by using tic to compile a terminal description with the feature added.  If you have root access on the HPUX machine, that's simple:

```
infocmp >foo
vi foo (adding the `smcup` and `rmcup` line)
sudo tic foo
```

Otherwise, you can work around it by setting the TERMINFO`environment variable to your own terminfo directory, and running`tic` to compile into *that* directory.  Something like

```
TERMINFO=$HOME/myterm; export TERMINFO
mkdir -p $TERMINFO/x
tic foo
```

(you would also need `TERMINFO` set in your shell for followup sessions).